# How to handle product delivery times in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a winform application and a mysql server saving the data.
I created a form from which users can save/update/delete records pretty normal stuff.

The problem comes when I added the delivery time functionality where the product has a expected, standard time in which it will be delivered; so say it has a six day expected time the form would calculate the expected time and show it back to the user, straight forward. 
I've tried using a **DATETIME** column but after reading mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) it has upper and lower limits so I cant´save say **'0000-00-01 12:30:00'**. So how do I save that kind of data into mysql? Whats standard practice in this topic?

Comment: What do you mean that the `DATETIME` has "upper" and "lower" limits? What does the date/time in the database represent? Is it the delivery duration in days? Or is it supposed to be an actual date/time?

Comment: [The `TIME` Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time.html) ranges from `'-838:59:59'` to `'838:59:59'`, i.e. approximately -35 to +35 days.  Is this sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Quote **The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.**. The DateTime in the database would represent a TimeSpan i think i missed that. The delivery times in the products range from mere minutes to 50 days

Comment: Explain why you think you need to store `0000-00-01 12:30:00` in your table.

Comment: I suggest you store the delivery duration as an integer, e.g. number of minutes to delivery completion.

Comment: @eggyal I tried your approach and I like the end results. Thanks!